# E-commerce variation product stock reduncy djanjo

Tags: python, django-models, size, stock, redundancy

I want to buy a shirt. Shirt can be many sizes. When I buy xl size shirt then xl size shirt also reduces from admin panel

I made only shirt quantity not size with quantity. Now can I solve this problem. From my admin panel panel I need to show product stock like
Name:Shirt
Size: XL
Stock: 20

not like
Name: Shirt
Stock: 20

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.